# Recurrence Relation: Robot can climb flight of n stairs 1 stair and land on either foot; 2 stairs & land on its left; or 3 stairs & land on its right

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinations

(a) Find a recurrence relation (with initial conditions) for the number of ways a robot can climb a flight of n stairs if at each step it can go up $1$ stair and land on either foot; or go up $2$ stairs and land on its left foot; or go up $3$ stairs and land on its right foot.

(b) Use your recurrence relation to find the number of ways the robot can climb a flight of 50 stairs.

(c) Repeat the question if additionally, the robot cannot land on its left foot twice in a row.

(d) Use your recurrence relation to find the number of ways the robot can climb a flight of 50 stairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{enclose}$

a) Let's start with the initial conditions (base cases)
The subscripts on **L** and **R** indicate the distance traveled
$R_1$ means **1 stair with the right foot**
$L_1$ means **1 stair with the left foot**
$R_2$ means **2 stair with the right foot**
$L_3$ means **3 stairs with the left foot**

- $a_0=1$  (Only 1 way to climb $0$ stairs)
- $a_1=2$  (Climb 1 stair with either foot)
- $a_2=5$

  - $R_2$ (Go up 2 stairs & land on the right foot)
  - $R_1R_1$, $L_1L_1$, $R_1L_1$ and $L_1R_1$ (**4 ways** to combine Left & Right foot movements of 1 stair)

The robot has 3 cases for whether it goes 1 stair, 2 stairs or 3

- $2a_{n-1}$ ($2$ ways to go up 1 stair & land on either foot, follow with an $n-1$ length sequence)
- $a_{n-2}$ ($1$ way to go 2 stairs & land on the left foot, follow with an $n-2$ length sequence since we used up 2 stairs)
- $a_{n-3}$ ($1$ way to go up 3 stairs and land on right foot)

Putting it altogether:
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$$

Let's verify $a_3$ by counting all the cases going **3 stairs**

$R_3$, $L_2L_1$, $L_2R_1$, $L_1L_2$, $R_1L_2$ ($5$ cases so far)
Plus $2^3=8$ combinations of $L_1$ and $R_1$ to go a total 3 stairs moving 1 stair at a time
$a_3=5+8$
$=13$

and using the recurrence relation & plugging in base cases gives the same answer
$a_3 = 2a_{3-1} + a_{3-2} + a_{3-3}$
$=2a_{2} + a_{1} + a_{0}$
$=2*5 + 2 + 1$
$=13$

b) Evaluating recurrence relations is tedious by hand, but in Wolfram Mathematica they are dead simple to input & evaluate

> (* Putting "a[n]=" after function definition speeds up calculation & avoids recursion overflow *)
>   a[n_]:= a[n]=2a[n-1]+a[n-2]+a[n-3]
>   a[0]=1;
>   a[1]=2;
>   a[2]=5;
>
> Now Evaluate it:
>   a[50]
>   Outputs: **156424759849575406340**

c) The restriction that it can't do 2 left feet in a row complicates it significantly. Any time a left move is made, we must follow it with a right foot move to avoid 2 left feet in a row

There are $6$ cases in the recurrence relation but we can combine the $2$ for $b_{n-3}$

- $b_{n-1}$ (1 stair with the right foot)
- $b_{n-3}$ (3 stairs with the right foot)
- $b_{n-2}$ (1 stair left foot, then follow with 1 stair right to avoid 2 left in a row. Used up 2 stairs so follow with valid $n-2$ sequence)
- $b_{n-3}$ (2 stairs left, then follow with 1 stair right)
- $b_{n-4}$ (1 stair left, follow with 3 stairs on the right foot)
- $b_{n-5}$ (2 stairs with left, follow with 3 stairs on the right)

Putting it together:
$$b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + 2b_{n-3} + b_{n-4} + b_{n-5}$$

Now counting the **base cases** also gets harder

- $b_0=1$ (1 way to go up no stairs)
- $b_1=2$ ($R_1$ or $L_1$  Simply right or left, no way to get 2 lefts in a row with just 1 step)
- $b_2=4$ ($R_2$, $R_1R_1$, $R_1L_1$ and $L_1R_1$. This excludes $L_1L_1$)
- $b_3=8$

  - ***5 cases*** going 1 step: $R_1R_1R_1$, $R_1R_1L_1$, $R_1L_1R_1$, $L_1R_1R_1$, $L_1R_1L_1$
  - ***2 cases*** using left 2 stairs: $L_2R_1$ and $R_1L_2$
  - ***1 case*** going up 3 stairs on the right: $R_3$
- $b_4=17$ (There are **$6$ kinds of cases** based on how many steps traveled (ways to add 1, 2 & 3 to equal 4, avoiding 2 lefts in a row) )

  - **1 1 1 1** = 1 stair each move

    - ***8 valid cases***: $R_1R_1R_1R_1$, $R_1R_1R_1L_1$, $R_1R_1L_1R_1$,  $R_1L_1R_1R_1$, $R_1L_1R_1L_1$, $L_1R_1R_1R_1$, $L_1R_1R_1L_1$, $L_1R_1L_1R_1$
    - This is probably the hardest one
    - Start by enumerating all 16 combinations of **L** and **R**
    - Imagine you're counting in binary with **R=**$0$ and **L=**$1$. So $R_1R_1R_1L_1=0001$ and $R_1L_1L_1R_1=0110$
      I've left them in the order of smallest to largest when read left to right
    - $R_1R_1R_1R_1$, $R_1R_1R_1L_1$, $R_1R_1L_1R_1$, $R_1R_1L_1L_1$ $R_1L_1R_1R_1$, $R_1L_1R_1L_1$, $R_1L_1L_1R_1$, $R_1L_1L_1L_1$, $L_1R_1R_1R_1$, $L_1R_1R_1L_1$, $L_1R_1L_1R_1$, $L_1R_1L_1L_1$, $L_1L_1R_1R_1$, $L_1L_1R_1L_1$, $L_1L_1L_1R_1$, $L_1L_1L_1L_1$
    - Cross out the ones with $2$ $L$'s
    - $R_1R_1R_1R_1$, $R_1R_1R_1L_1$, $R_1R_1L_1R_1$, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ R_1R_1L_1L_1, }$ $R_1L_1R_1R_1$, $R_1L_1R_1L_1$, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ R_1L_1L_1R_1, }$ $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ R_1L_1L_1L_1, }$ $L_1R_1R_1R_1$, $L_1R_1R_1L_1$, $L_1R_1L_1R_1$, $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ L_1R_1L_1L_1, }$ $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ L_1L_1R_1R_1, }$ $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ L_1L_1R_1L_1, }$ $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ L_1L_1L_1R_1, }$ $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{ L_1L_1L_1L_1 }$
    - This leaves you with the 8 from above
  - **1 2 1**=1 stair followed by 2 stairs then 1 stair

    - ***1 valid case:*** $R_1L_2R_1$ (Left foot going 2 stairs forces the surrounding steps to be with the right)
  - **2 1 1**=2 stairs 1st then 1 stair and 1 stair

    - ***2 valid cases:*** $L_1R_1R_1$ and $L_2R_1L_1$
  - **1 1 2**=1 stair then 1 stair then 2 stairs

    - ***2 valid cases:*** $R_1R_1L_2$ and $L_1R_1L_2$
  - **1 3**=1 stair then 3 stairs

    - ***2 valid cases:*** $R_1R_3$ and $L_1R_3$
  - **3 1**=3 stairs then 1 stair

    - ***2 valid cases:*** $R_3R_1$ and $R_3L_1$
  - Notice we skip **2 2** since left foot is the only foot than can move 2 at a time we are avoiding 3 lefts in a row

d) Again, hard to by hand, but using Mathematica:

> b[n_]:= b[n] = b[n-1] + b[n-2] + 2b[n-3] + b[n-4] + b[n-5]
>   b[0]=1;
>   b[1]=2;
>   b[2]=4;
>   b[3]=8;
>   b[4]=17;
>
> Now Evaluate it: 
>   b[50]
>   Outputs: 10020502088013274

Comment: How did you answer so fast?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Saw this question before, but then it got removed and I've been refining my answer and someone reposted it

Comment: @SleekPanther That seems to happen a lot.